# Chromecast CAF v3: Shaka Player - Widevine, I can't configure the certificates

Tags: chromecast, widevine, caf, shaka

I am migrating an application developed in sdk v2 to v3 I understand that it uses shaka player,
but I can't find a way to configure the preferences of the player, specifically I am looking to configure this in the player:

```
    drm: {
      servers: {
        'com.widevine.alpha': media.server_url,
      },
      advanced: {
        'com.widevine.alpha': {
          videoRobustness: 'SW_SECURE_CRYPTO',
          audioRobustness: 'SW_SECURE_CRYPTO',
        },
      },
    },
```

Without succeeding, I would appreciate if someone could guide me a little.

If this is not possible, I would like to know how I can set my own player in the framework.